# How to clear the fields of list in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am looking for how to clear the list when iterating in a for each loop?

Code :

Here I have a class

```
class Emailmembers
{
    public string _firstName { get; set; }
    public string _lastName { get; set; }
    public string _Address { get; set; }
    public string _subscribe { get; set; } 
}
```

and a list

```
List<Emailmembers> emailmembers = new List<Emailmembers>();
```

and a for each loop iterating

```
foreach(string[] item in body) 
{
    /* here I will get the fields 
    1.FName
    2.LName
    3.Address
    4.Subscribe*/
```

Finally adding the above fields to the list

```
emailmembers.Add(new Emailmembers
                {
                    _address = Address,
                    _firstName = FirstName,
                    _lastName = LastName,
                    _subscribe = Subscribe    
                });       
             }
```

After this how to clear my fields such that the old values will be added to my list and **cleared**, therefore it will go for another loop for new field values.
I used emailmembers.clear(); which makes the count to be zero?

very much thankful if any help...

Comment: what? `such that the old values will be added to my list and cleared` can you write pseudocode for what you want to occur?

Answer (score 1):

The values are in the object and not in the class.

To show you how, try these steps: After loop is completed, create another object of `Emailmembers`. Put a break point on a code like after this line like this

```
} //Loop ends here

Emailmembers em = new Emailmembers();

em._address = "Foo"; //Put a break point here
```

Now look at the properties of `em`. All being string type, they will be `null` which proves that your values are not retained.

Answer (score 0):

create fileds inside the loop and then for each loop item those fields will clear automatically

```
foreach(string[] item in body) 
{
  var address = // set the address;
  var firstName= // set the FirstName;
  var lastName= // set the LastName;
  var subscribe    = // set the Subscribe;
  emailmembers.Add(new Emailmembers
                {
                    _address = address,
                    _firstName = firstName,
                    _lastName = lastName,
                    _subscribe = subscribe    
                });  
}
```